# Maven - Enforce minimal requirement across org

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

In our organisation we have many java project which use maven, many, many!

We would like to enforce the minimal requirement for plugins versions, dependencies and so on (e.g. jdk_version > 8 or sonar-plugin > 7.6 and so on).

We can do this in different ways, for example using something like the enforce plugin or simply with properties, plugin and dependency management.

**The easier way would be to define by default that all the project would declare the same pom as parent**, this pom.xml would contain the enforce plugin or the properties/plugins configuration, this then would get inherited by all the projects.

The problem is that some of our projects (a big part) need to refer as parent to Spring Boot pom.xml (it is so useful as we inherit a number of configuration properties and dependencies).

So this blocks the idea of the common parent pom (yes, we could use the spring boot as parent of the common parent pom but then many projects that don't require spring boot would inherit a number of plugin/dependencies/configuration which may potentially cause issues to them)

Using a dependency type pom, scope import, would also not work cause it imports just dependencies (excluding plugin a properties )..

Is there any other "clean" way to do this?

Comment: spring boot can also being used as import bom so no need to define spring-boot-parent as parent of your own parent which would result in many updates cause spring boot updates at least with minor versions every 6 month...

Comment: If you define your own corporate pom there you should define plugin versions and based configurations. The import of spring boot should be done on a project level not on the parent...

Comment: If we import it, we would have to re-declare all the properties for the dependencies version in the parent, and these properties would get inherited also by project not using spring-boot because not in the same level of the spring booth imported pom

Comment: No you don't have to. You seemed to misunderstand the bom import-scope concept. There is no need to define properties for dependencies. Use dependencyManagement if you define a set of dependencies in your corporate pom...which I not recommend. Make a separate pom (dependency pom) and import that as scope import which only contains a dependencyMangement with the dependencies. No need for properties.

Comment: Sorry I really don't get what you are suggesting, i create a dependency pom and then I import it, I will import all the dependencies management, but i want to be able to control the versions of these dependencies from the top so that anyone importing this pom will be using the minimal required versions, how are you suggesting to do this then?